# ASP.net MVC favicon doesn't show up

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, gzip, asp.net-mvc-routing, favicon

I need some help with showing the favicon on my site while using ASP.NET MVC.

The problem in short is that whenever a request is made for

- http://example.com/favicon.ico OR
- http://example.com/Content/favicon.ico

the request never gets served. Firefox says :

> Content Encoding Error - The page you
>   are trying to view cannot be shown
>   because it uses an invalid or
>   unsupported form of compression.

I have tried ignoring the route using the following ignore route strategies, obviously not all at the same time ;-)

```
routes.Add(new Route("favicon.ico", new StopRoutingHandler()));
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });
routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{file}", new { file = @".*" });
```

I can confirm that it is ignoring the route because I subclassed the controller factory and it does not call `CreateController`
The kicker is this, I also have a png version of the file and it does get served. I have also checked it with fiddler and whenever I try to request the ico directly through url I get a pop-up that says something like this:

> The magic number in GZip header is not
>   correct. Make sure you are passing in
>   a GZip stream.

So it seems that somehow IIS is trying to send it back compressed?
How do I stop this behavior/make it work?

Any insights?

**UPDATE:**

I figured it out, the web.config had a custom httpmodule that dealt with serving physical files and it was trying to compress the file output. That doesn't work when you have image files. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Why are you adding it as a route??

Just add this to your master page header:

```
  <link rel="shortcut icon" media="all" type="image/x-icon" href="<%= Url.Content("~/favicon.ico") %>" />
```

Comment: I'm not adding it as a route, I'm trying to ignore it. I already have that html link element in my master page. That's the point. The icon is not being returned, somehow when it is being requested the browser is not understanding what it's getting back.